# How to properly use expression results as booleans on Azure Devops pipelines?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm trying to use an `or` expression to define a boolean on a template as follows:

```yaml
parameters:
  - name: A
    default: true
  - name: B
    default: false

stages:
  - template: bacon.yml@template
    parameters:
      booleanParameter: or(eq(${{ parameters.A }}, true), eq(${{ parameters.B}}, true))
```

In my head, it should work just fine, yet I keep getting this same error:

```
The 'booleanParameter' parameter value 'or(eq(True, true), eq(False, true))' is not a valid Boolean.
```

I've tried some small variations of syntax, all of them resulting in the same error.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should use template expression to wrap whole expression:

```
booleanParameter: ${{ or(eq(parameters.A, true), eq(parameters.B, true)) }}
```

Comment: It acctually just returns the very same error `The 'booleanParameter' parameter value 'or(eq(True, 'True'), eq(False, 'True'))' is not a valid Boolean.`

Comment: I changed my reply. Now it passing validation and works.

Comment: I can confirm that the `eq` expression expects a boolean value like `true`, not a string like `'true'`.

Comment: @DvS you can pass anything. If you do eq it means equals. So "true" equals "true" and true equals true. If you do eq(parameters.B, true) B should be true. But if you do eq(parameters.B, 'true') parameter should be "true"